# Div dynamic width in two columns and border

Tags: css, html

I've run into interesting problem while creating navigation bar with two dynamic size columns and a search box between them, and clickable tabs on left and right sides. Here is the code for the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.nav{
font-size: 14px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
color:white;
}

.nav .l-table {
display: table;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.nav .l-table .l-cell {
display: table-cell;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 95px;
}

.nav .l-table .l-cell.clickable {
background: gray;
}

.nav .l-table .l-cell.stretch{
min-width: 60px;
width: auto;
border-right: 1px solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="nav">
    <div class="l-table">
        <div class="l-cell clickable">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="stretch l-cell"></div>

        <div style="width:300px;" class="l-cell clickable">
                   <input type="text" value="Search"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="stretch l-cell"></div>

        <div class="l-cell clickable">
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
</div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice how two black areas shrink while window is resizing. This is the behaviour I want, so that navigation bar adjusts its size depening on the size of screen.

The problem I have is that I don't need `border-right` in `.nav .l-table .l-cell.stretch` elements, but when I remove them from css, behaviour becomes different and width: auto doesn't work.

Do you maybe have a clue what might be the problem? It is strange that removing the border causes this, it seems like a bug to me.

Also do you have other suggestionss how to make the same navigation with different css?

Thank you.

Comment: I can not reproduce what your are describing. Check out the fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/wYzGg/3/. The black areas are the same width for me. Does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: I've tried in my versions of Chrome and Firefox, I am not sure why is it like that in fiddle, but thank you for trying to help me anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using quite a mess of fixed and variable width properties. May I suggest, if your problem allows, to use solely relative width definitions.

That is:

```
.nav .l-table .l-cell {
display: table-cell;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width:5%;
min-width: 95px;
}

.nav .l-table .l-cell.clickable {
background: gray;
}

.nav .l-table .l-cell.clickable2 {
background: gray;
width:20%;
min-width:300px;
}

.nav .l-table .l-cell.stretch{
min-width: 60px;
width: 35%;
}
```

(The clickable2 class is for the center search box. Change the class name there and get rid of the width in line style.)